# audioManager.startBluetoothSco() is not working on android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm setting up AudioManager with bluetooth to record an audio , the code is already there but not working and whenever i check for AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE , it never connects and returns -1 , i do not know why , can anyone please guide me to solve this issue , Thank you .

- This is my receiver

```
   public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    
    public CallReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle;
        String state;
        String incomingNumber;
        String action = intent.getAction();


        int BLE = intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1); // always return -1 
        if (BLE == AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED){  // never connected
            // start bluetooth headset
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)
            audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
            audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
            audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
        }

    }
}
```

- Receiver in Manifest File

```
  <receiver
            android:name=".recorder.CallReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
             
           <action android:name="android.media.extra.SCO_AUDIO_STATE"/>
           <action 
           android:name="android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: I think the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getIntExtra(java.lang.String,%20int)) is very clear on that: _-1_ is the default value you pass to the function as the second parameter and means that `AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE` was not previously added to the intent.

Comment: what exactly did you not understand in the description of the function `getIntExtra()`?

Comment: too little code to conclude the error, but an example: Your code query the action but doesn't check it. Maybe the callBack is called with a different intent than the one you expect?

Comment: @Risto the code is supposed to check if wireless headphones are connected or not  , if connected then right after i start the bluetooth sco , i have added the constants into receiver class in my manifest file , i connect my headphones to bluetooth and start checking for the intent inside the call receiver class .. more than that what is possible to check for !!

Answer (score 0):

Before checking the current state, first need to find the action, I check for AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, it never connects and returns -1. After finding the current state, If found 'SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED' setBluetoothScoOn and startBluetoothSco.

```
 @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED))
        {
            int currentState = context . getIntExtra (AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1);
            Log.d("Bluetooth Connect - ", "Audio SCO: " + AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED);
            switch(currentState) {
                case AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED :
                {
                    Log.i("Bluetooth Connect", "SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED");
                    AudioManager audioManager =(AudioManager) context . getSystemService (Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)
                    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                    audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
                    audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
                }
                break;
                case AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED :
                {
                    Log.e("Bluetooth disconnect", "SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                }
                break;
                default: Log.e("Bluetooth unknown - ", "unknown state received:"+l_state);
            }
        } else Log.e("Bluetooth Connect - ", "onReceive:action=" + action);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply , i'm using your code and still shows the same output , check this image from my logs , thank you https://ibb.co/YXP7mYQ

Answer (score 0):

I think your call to audioManager.startBluetoothSco(); will trigger the BroadcastReceiver and you will receive your state connected for example use state audioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED to startBluetoothSco

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).